# Changing data format to american format

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get some advice regarding how to change to date format to the Gregorian calendar (american) one (mine is in Bhuddist calendar (thai) with year in Bhuddist calendar for the year part).

I ran the code and the date came up as `26.06.2562` where I want it to be `26.06.2019`.

```
Sub header_adding ()
    dates = Now()
    dates = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")

    ws.Range("J1").Value = "GI status as of" & " " & dates
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the answers to this question on the Microsoft Community forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-change-deault-year/fc7760b5-4965-43b6-a68b-6ffa1e3fa10a), Excel does not have a setting of its own for deciding on what the default year is. However you can change your system date to the "American" one, and Excel should now use this new year as the default.

The answers also links [to this page by Allen Wyatt](https://excel.tips.net/T003360_Modifying_Default_Year_for_Dates.html) which presents a macro for modifying the default year if you are in the first few months of the year. Modifying it to modify the year of *any* date you enter should be simple enough:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsDate(Target) Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = DateAdd("yyyy", -543, Target)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: hey, what if I want it to be American by default (locale to always be American) do I have to set it from application?

Comment: From how I understood the thread I linked to, if you set your system clock to American format, Excel should also use this. I.e. you just need to right click the clock in your toolbar, select adjust time and date settings, and then change the date there to the format you want. @NathathaiA

Answer (score 1):

You would need to calculate, you cannot just format.
See https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+convert+gregorian+to+thai+date

So you must subtract `543` from your buddhist year.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub header_adding()
    Dim GregorianDate As String
    GregorianDate = Format$(DateSerial(Year(Date) - 543, Month(Date), Day(Date)), "dd.mm.yyyy")

    ws.Range("J1").Value = "GI status as of" & " " & GregorianDate 
End Sub
```

Comment: hey, what if I want it to be American by default (locale to always be American) do I have to set it from application?

Comment: @NathathaiA If you want it to be American (Gregorian) you need to [change your Windows date format](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10) to American (Gregorian).